# Drawing a line in PostGIS using Nearest Neighbour Method

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, nearest-neighbor

*This is a cross post from an email I sent to the PostGIS mailing list*

So far in my endeavor to create a line between a point and its projected
location on a line has been long but I'm almost there. As of yesterday, and
before including any nearest neighbor analysis, I got the results shown in
this image:

[image: QGis screenshot]

As you can see, each point in pink is connecting to all the projected points, whereas, I only want to connect each pink x to its respective projection.

On IRC, It was recommended that I use [BostonGIS's nearest neighbor method](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic). I inputed the function to PostgreSQL and tried it unsuccessfully as outlined below. I am assuming that my error is due the wrong parameter type. I played around with that, changed some of the columns' type to varchar, but still I can't get it to work.

Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong? any suggestions on how to fix it?

Code:

```
-- this sql script creates a line table that connects points 

-- convert multi lines into lines

CREATE TABLE exploded_roads AS
SELECT the_geom
FROM (
    SELECT ST_GeometryN(
    the_geom,
    generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(the_geom)))
    AS the_geom 
    FROM "StreetCenterLines"
)
AS foo;


-- Create line table that'll connect the centroids to the projected points on exploded lines
CREATE TABLE lines_from_centroids_to_roads (
    the_geom    geometry,
    edge_id SERIAL
);

-- Populate Table
INSERT INTO lines_from_centroids_to_roads ( the_geom )
SELECT
    ST_MakeLine(
        centroids.the_geom,
        (pgis_fn_nn(centroids.the_geom, 1000000, 1,1000, 'exploded_roads' ,'true', 'gid',
            ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(
                exploded_roads.the_geom,
                ST_Line_Locate_Point(
                    exploded_roads.the_geom,
                    centroids.the_geom
                )
            )
        )).*
    )
FROM exploded_roads, fred_city_o6_da_centroids centroids;

DROP TABLE exploded_roads;
```

**ERROR**

```
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "lines_from_centroids_to_roads_edge_id_seq" for serial column "lines_from_centroids_to_roads.edge_id"

ERROR:  function pgis_fn_nn(geometry, integer, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, geometry) does not exist
LINE 28:   (pgis_fn_nn(centroids.the_geom, 1000000, 1,1000, 'exploded...
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


********** Error **********

ERROR: function pgis_fn_nn(geometry, integer, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, geometry) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 584
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out I don't need to use nearest neighbour after all. I assigned an id identical to the centroids to which i'm connecting the lines through

```
-- this sql script creates a line table that connects points 

-- delete existing tables if they exist
DROP TABLE exploded_roads;
DROP TABLE projected_points;
DROP TABLE lines_from_centroids_to_roads;


-- convert multi lines into lines
CREATE TABLE exploded_roads (
    the_geom    geometry,
    edge_id     serial
);

-- insert the linestring that don't need to be converted
INSERT INTO exploded_roads
SELECT the_geom
FROM "StreetCenterLines"
WHERE st_geometrytype(the_geom) = 'ST_LineString';


INSERT INTO exploded_roads
SELECT the_geom
FROM (
    SELECT ST_GeometryN(
    the_geom,
    generate_series(1, ST_NumGeometries(the_geom)))
    AS the_geom 
    FROM "StreetCenterLines"
)
AS foo;





-- create projected points table with ids matching centroid table
CREATE TABLE projected_points (
    the_geom    geometry,
    pid     serial,
    dauid       int
);


-- Populate Table
INSERT INTO projected_points(the_geom, dauid)
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("DAUID")
    ( 
        ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(
            exploded_roads.the_geom,
            ST_Line_Locate_Point(
                exploded_roads.the_geom,
                centroids.the_geom
            )
        )
    ),
    (centroids."DAUID"::int)

FROM exploded_roads, fred_city_o6_da_centroids centroids;


-- Create Line tables
CREATE TABLE lines_from_centroids_to_roads (
    the_geom    geometry,
    edge_id SERIAL
);


-- Populate Line Table
INSERT INTO lines_from_centroids_to_roads(
SELECT
    ST_MakeLine( centroids.the_geom, projected_points.the_geom )
FROM projected_points, fred_city_o6_da_centroids centroids
WHERE projected_points.dauid = centroids."DAUID"::int
);

-- Delete temp tables
--DROP TABLE exploded_roads;
--DROP TABLE projected_points;
```

Comment: Why do you use `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point`? Shouldnt be the location of the point on the line be clear with `ST_Line_Locate_Point`?

Answer (score 1):

A problem would be that I think the function expects the [second argument (distguess) to be a double precision](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic) instead of an integer. Try 1000000.0 or try casting to float explicitely...

Comment: I tried both and that didn't fix it, but kudos on the notice.

Comment: A guess, but i'd try writing the 'exploded_roads' ,'true', 'gid' - part as ''exploded_roads'' ,''true'', ''gid'' or "exploded_roads" ,"true", "gid"... Are you using a tool like pgadmin to run this query?

Comment: I'm using PgAdmin to run the queries. the '' true '' returns an error now : 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "true"
LINE 28: ...the_geom, 1000000.0, 1,1000, "exploded_roads" , ''true'', "g...

Comment: with that error, i tried changing ''true '' to 'true' "true" with no vain. I also tried to change "true" to "DAUID" >0 " (one of the fields in centroids)